# Stuck in ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

Tags: sql, jsp

I don't see where the problem is. 
It keeps showing ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns
Last thing I did was to add

```
substrb(TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130601','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYYMMDD'), -4, 2) ||'월'AS MONTH
```

Following the the whole query. I've been stuck in this for 2 days now...
Can anyone help?

```
SELECT X.*
  FROM
      ( 
        SELECT 
                    (CASE
                             WHEN DAY.DAY = 'SUM' THEN DAY.DAY
                             ELSE TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (DAY.DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') 
                       END
                    ) AS DAY,
                    DAY.WEEK,
                    MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT AS MNOT_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE_500K AS MOVIE_500K_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE_1M AS MOVIE_1M_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE AS MOVIE_CNT,
                    RSC.EXAM AS EXAM_CNT,
                    RSC.WEB AS WEB_CNT,
                    RSC.IMG AS IMG_CNT,
                    RSC.INTERRAC AS INTERRACTIVE_CNT,
                    RSC.DOC AS DOC_CNT,
                    MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT + RSC.MOVIE_500K + RSC.MOVIE_1M + RSC.MOVIE + RSC.EXAM + RSC.WEB + RSC.IMG + RSC.INTERRAC + RSC.DOC TOT_CNT
          FROM 
                    /* DATES */



(SELECT 
                    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130601','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS DAY
                   ,ceil(
                          (
                            to_number(substrb(TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130601','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYYMMDD'), -2, 2)) 
                          + 7 
                          - to_number(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130601','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD'),'D'))
                          )/7 
                         )|| ' WEEK' AS WEEK,

                         substrb(TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130601','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYYMMDD'), -4, 2) ||'MONTH'AS MONTH

                         from DUAL

                   CONNECT BY TO_DATE('20130601', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + LEVEL - 1  <=  TO_DATE('20130830', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                  UNION ALL
                      SELECT 'SUM', '' FROM DUAL
                    ) DAY LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   /* RESOURCE */
                    (
                     SELECT 
                                 NVL(DT_G.COMM_DT, 'SUM') COMM_DT
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE_500K), 0) AS MOVIE_500K
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE_1M), 0) AS MOVIE_1M
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE), 0) AS MOVIE
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.EXAM), 0) AS EXAM
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.DOC), 0) AS DOC 
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.IMG), 0) AS IMG
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.WEB), 0) AS WEB
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.INTERRAC), 0) AS INTERRAC
                       FROM 
                                (
                                 SELECT
                                              COMM_DT
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_500K END MOVIE_500K
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_1M END AS MOVIE_1M
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_500K+SUMT.SUM_1M END AS MOVIE
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP11' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS EXAM
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP12' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS DOC
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP13' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS IMG
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP14' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS WEB
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP01' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS INTERRAC
                                  FROM (
                                              SELECT RSC_TP_DSCD, SUM(STDY_CNT) AS SUM_STD_CNT, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M) AS SUM_1M, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K) AS SUM_500K, COMM_DT
                                              FROM (
                                                        SELECT RSC_SNO, STDY_CNT, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K, COMM_DT
                                                          FROM LRMS.V_EBSM_PKG_RSC_COMM_CNT
                                                        WHERE PKG_SNO = 0  AND RSC_SNO != 0
                                                        AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130501', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130530', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
                                                        ) CNT
                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN LRMS.V_LRRM_RSC RSC ON CNT.RSC_SNO = RSC.RSC_SNO
                                              GROUP BY RSC_TP_DSCD, COMM_DT
                                            ) SUMT
                                ) DT_G
                         GROUP BY ROLLUP(DT_G.COMM_DT)
                    ) RSC ON DAY.DAY = RSC.COMM_DT

                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (
                      SELECT NVL(SUM(STDY_CNT), 0) AS SUM_STD_CNT, NVL(COMM_DT, 'SUM') COMM_DT
                        FROM LRMS.V_EBSM_PKG_RSC_COMM_CNT
                      WHERE PKG_SNO != 0  AND RSC_SNO = 0
                                AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130601', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130830', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
                      GROUP BY ROLLUP(COMM_DT)
                    ) MNOT  ON DAY.DAY = MNOT.COMM_DT
        ) X

 WHERE 1=1
 and X.TOT_CNT IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its this subselect:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130601','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS DAY,
    ceil( ... ) || ' WEEK' AS WEEK,
    substrb( ... ) ||'MONTH'AS MONTH
from DUAL
CONNECT BY TO_DATE('20130601', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + LEVEL - 1  <=  TO_DATE('20130830', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUM', '' FROM DUAL
```

In a `UNION ALL` you need the same number of items in the select lists for both selects. You added MONTH to the first so you need to add something to the second:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130601','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS DAY,
    ceil( ... ) || ' WEEK' AS WEEK,
    substrb( ... ) ||'MONTH'AS MONTH
from DUAL
CONNECT BY TO_DATE('20130601', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + LEVEL - 1  <=  TO_DATE('20130830', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'SUM', /*DAY*/ 
    '',    /*WEEK*/
    ''     /*MONTH*/ 
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

On Xie answer and your comment on this answer --
You can edit query like below

One more thing you are giving wrong date format while changing char to date (in 'to_date' function)

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130601','YYYYMMDD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYY.MM.DD') AS DAY,
    ceil( ... ) || ' WEEK' AS WEEK,
    substrb( ... ) ||'MONTH'AS MONTH
from DUAL
CONNECT BY TO_DATE('20130601', 'YYYYMMDD') + LEVEL - 1  <=  TO_DATE('20130830', 'YYYYMMDD')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUM', '' as week,'' as month FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @pratik garg. So I fixed the whole query, and ran it. It does show the columns, including MOMTH. However, no data are displaying when I add the MONTH column. 
It does show the data when I don't include the MONTH. Do you know where is wrong with this?